# Firehose is unable to assume role

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I'm trying to use [Firehose API (JS)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Firehose.html) and I keep getting the following error:

> "InvalidArgumentException: Firehose is unable to assume role
>   arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXX:role/NAME. Please check the role provided.

I check the role and I have set my custom policy to include all resources for STS and Firehose action. I have no clue why this error exists if I'm allowing `AssumeRole` under STS.

#### Method Calling

The method I'm using is `createDeliveryStream(params = {}, callback)` with `S3DestinationConfiguration`.

#### Policy JSON

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:*",
                "kinesisvideo:*",
                "s3:PutAccountPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:GetAccountPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:*",
                "firehose:*",
                "sts:*",
                "s3:HeadBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: It would be far easier to answer if you actually showed the role in your question. But I suspect that you're missing the `Principal` element.

Comment: I agree I will update that soon. AWS Console is down. I Agree with you, I try to set principle but it gives me some error which I will also update that as well.

Comment: @guest Updated.

Comment: Can you check the trust relationship defined in the IAM role and verify that it is set to `firehose.amazonaws.com`?

Comment: @krishna_mee2004 Thank you so much. That resolved the issue. I will accept your answer.

Comment: Cool, I will type that up. Glad to help

Comment: I barely see any doc for this.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Please check the trust relationship defined in the IAM role and verify that it is set to `firehose.amazonaws.com`. Policy defined in Trust relationship enables services to assume the role. For Kinesis Firehose, refer [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/controlling-access.html) document which contains details about IAM roles for Firehose. Refer "Grant Kinesis Data Firehose Access to an Amazon S3 Destination" section in the document which mentions about trust policy.